# DataTable Filter using Prime Faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to prime faces. I am learning and trying to develop some sample code using Data Table. Data table is getting rendered. When I try to use filter option it is not working.

If any one could help in solving the issue or provide a simple example of Data Table using filtering, it would be great.

I have tried the example given in primefaces.org site but it doesn't work out. Moreover I am not sure whether I need to write any code in the back end to perform filter or any change needs to be done in the index.xhtml file.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Please find below the sample code which I am trying...

---

### **index.xhtml** -- I have used only one column to display for testing purpose.

```
<div xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view>
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}">

        <p:column id="modelColumn" filterBy="model" headerText="Model" footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains" >
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column> 
 </p:dataTable>
 </f:view>
</div>
```

**CarBean.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "carBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable{
    private List<Car> cars = null;
    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }
    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
    public CarBean()
    {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        cars.add(new Car("swift","2013","maruti","black"));
        cars.add(new Car("i20","2014","hyundai","grey"));
        cars.add(new Car("figo","2012","ford","red"));
    }
}
```

---

### **Car.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Car implements Serializable{
    private String model;
    private String year;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String color;
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Car(String model, String year, String manufacturer, String color)
    {
             this.model = model;
             this.year = year; 
             this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
             this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this example:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

you need a filteredValue attribute on the datatable. It should just point to a List on the bean with getters and setters. Dont populate this list, PF will do that behind your back.

Also you miss the widgetVar attribute, not sure what this does though.

Answer (score -1):

Change column `filterby` option like with bean refernce variable

```
filterBy="#{car.model}"
```

Comment: The use of filterBy="model" is totally acceptable as shown in the primefaces showcase and should work

Comment: the new showcase was updated to match the new PF5 handling. the use of filterBy="model" is deprecated but should still work!